# How to make an Infinite Html5 Canvas which can be zoomed and panned?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, zooming

I was working on a real time whiteboard.
I want to create an Infinite canvas, which can be zoomed using the mouse wheel and panned using drag, using javascript.During the zoom and pan the items drawn on the canvas must also be affected. Is there a was to achieve this without using any external library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but it'll take a bit of work. The general idea of what you'll do is the following:

- You will need to keep track of the position of the "camera", as well as how close it is to the content - a zoom factor
- You will need to attach event listeners to different mouse actions to cause the camera's state to change
- When you drag or zoom, you will need to redraw your canvas with the new positions and sizes of all the content. Some math will have to be done to know what the new canvas content is.
- There may or may not be certain performance issues you have to address if there's a lot of content on the canvas.

An alternative, possibly quicker approach, but maybe less powerful, would be to not use canvas, and use some CSS magic instead with plain HTML. The basic concept here is that you'll have a 0x0 div as your plane. That div will contain your content, which may include content such as custom SVGs. Each of its children will break out of the div, and will be positioned relative to it. When you drag, you just move the div (through transform: translate()). When you zoom, you just scale the div (through transform: scale()).

Some useful references if taking the second approach:

- [CSS transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) - to move and scale the whiteboard
- [CSS position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) - to position content on the whiteboard, and for the general layout
- [CSS overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) - to crop the whiteboard

Comment: Just to recommend looking at the second approach mentioned here. I have tried moving along a very long canvas by redrawing and cpu usage was massive. The laptop got very hot. Using ordinary transform etc on HTML elements was fine.

Comment: The problem is it a real time board , where 2 or more users write on it simultaneously. Just check out this board : [link](https://awwapp.com/b/) , try zooming and panning the board. I want it something like that. The user can have free hand drawing, draw rectangle, circle ..etc.  So I think , It'll be best to use a canvas. Can i use the second method you mentioned for this ?

Comment: @Aditya yes you can. The source of the whiteboard content won't change the logic for actually rendering the whiteboard's. Anything, (user events or server events) can provide content to the whiteboard.

Answer (score 1):

The canvas element itself won't be infinite, I guess that's clear enough. What will change when you drag and zoom is the mapping of the real coordinates of your whiteboard elements to the drawing coordinates on the canvas. There's some work to do with detecting the mouse events and doing the calculations for updating the mapping, so there are too many specifics to really put in an answer. But yes of course this is possible without an external library.

Answer (score 1):

Basically canvas could not be set to infinite sized. All you can do is to draw the portion that should be visible in the canvas.

first of all you should store all the points you have drawn to an array.

whenever you pan your canvas , track the offset that you have panned. this offset values can be used to reposition your stored points in your canvas.

eg. suppose you have drawn a line from (50 , 50) to (100 , 100).

let the offsets be {x:0 , y:0}

x , y offsets shows how much x and y distances you have panned in total

then update the points by adding the offsets and redraw

https://github.com/TomHumphries/InfiniteCanvasWhiteboard

here is a simple html5 whiteboard created by Tom Humphries which has infinite zoom and pan.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32369935)

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. I shall update my answer. Feel free to ask your doubts too